# How to find missing attendance from the database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table first is employee table and second is attendance table. Now i want to find all missing attendance of each employee of a given month. All missing dates should be come in list.

Employee Table

```
emp_code emp_name
  1        A
  2        B
```

Attendance Table

```
 emp_code    Log_Date
     1      2017-04-01  
     1      2017-04-02 
     1      2017-04-03   
     2      2017-04-01  
     2      2017-04-02 
     2      2017-04-03
```

Expected Result

```
 emp_code    Log_Date
     1      2017-04-04  
     1      2017-04-05 
     1      2017-04-06 
            .
            .
     1      2017-04-30 
     2      2017-04-04  
     2      2017-04-05 
     2      2017-04-06 
            .
            .
     2      2017-04-30
```

Comment: show us some code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct answer of my question.

I created a month_days table where i inserted all days of 12 months.

```
id date
1  2017-04-1
2  2017-04-2
3  2017-04-3
.
.
30 2017-04-30
31  2017-05-1
32  2017-05-2
33  2017-05-3
.
.
34 2017-05-31
```

This is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM month_days d
CROSS JOIN employees e
LEFT JOIN attendances l ON d.date = DATE( l.log_date ) AND 
e.emp_code = l.emp_code
WHERE l.emp_code IS NULL
GROUP BY d.date, e.emp_code
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT e.emp_name, a.log_date FROM employee e
INNER JOIN attendance a
ON
(e.emp_code = a.emp_code)
AND a.log_date = '';